# Interpreting Neural Network with scaled input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, scaling

I'm currently having a seminar in university about Neural Networks in economics. My goal is to predict a companies value based on 15 input features.
I implemented my first Neural Network for that task. 
My current Problem is, that I don't know how to interpret the loss function, after scaling the data.
Do I just rescale it?

This is the part of my Code where I scale the data. It is used afterwards for crossvalidation.

```
scaler_X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
scaler_y = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(y)

X_scaled = scaler_X.transform(X)
y_scaled = scaler_y.transform(y)
```

The loss function I use is the mean squared arror and the resulting error is around 0.0062.

Thanks in advance for any help, Robin

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

x_scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled = x_scaler.fit_transform(X)

y_scaler = StandardScaler()
y_scaled = y_scaler.fit_transform(y)
```

I am assuming, your model gives y_pred as the output. we have to use the `y_scaler` to rescale the data and compare with ground truth values.

```
y_rescaled = y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)
mean_squared_error(y_true, y_rescaled)
```